# "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" - WCF REST service in Azure

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, azure

I am having problems when invoking the method in my winJS app :

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
           ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json,
           BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest)]
void newUserAndImageEntry(string pArrayImage,
    string pContentType, string pUserName, string pFileName);
```

The error I'm getting is :

```
 "InnerException":null
 "Message":"Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
 "StackTrace":"
    at WebRoleUploadImages.UploadImagesAJAX.newUserAndImageEntry(String pArrayImage,
       String pContentType, String pUserName, String pFileName)
    at SyncInvokenewUserAndImageEntry(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
    at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance,
       Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
    at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
    at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
    at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc& rpc)
    at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
Type:"System.Exception"}
```

I dont really know how to even find which is the object that is null..I checked all the variables im sending and they all have at least something, help?

Comment: The error message could be talking about any variable used during the entire function call, including local variables in the method itself that you create during the processing.   I would suggest running the code directly in an IDE like Visual Studio and see where the code is failing.  If it's a problem specific to Azure, use the Azure Emulator to simulate the entire request/response cycle through the service, which can be done through Visual Studio as well with the debugger attached.

Comment: If you had .pdb files you would get much more useful info, including the exact line in the source file where the exception is thrown from. That would be a good start.

Comment: sharptooth you opened a new world for me, thank you